# "Group" is a required value when creating a new order from backend

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, backend

After I upgraded to Magento 1.9.3.4 this error message appears when creating a new order with a new client:

"Group" is a required value.

I tried selecting a different group (default is General) but it's the same. It was working before the update.

[image: screenshot with Group is a required value error message]

Comment: Before upgrade, which version of magento have you used ?

Comment: I was using 1.9.3.3.

Comment: Do you have any third party modules that use customer groups?

Comment: I don't have any third party modules that are related to customer groups.

Answer (score 0):

May be this is something with customer attribute 'group'.
Let me know your full progress.

1. Do you create new customer at time of new order?
2. Do you use already existed customer at time of new order?
3. If 1st is 'yes' than have you checked weather customer is created in admin customer grid or not, and `yes` created than does it field group has customer group value?
4. Is all ok from customer grid and also check the same by editing customer, than try to get same customer data by custom script.

Please check all possibilities and than let me know. which one is working and which not.

Comment: I am creating the customer at the time of order. That is when the issue appears. If I first create the customer and then go to create the order (by this using an existing customer) then it's working without any problems. I don't really understand what you are trying to say at 3) and 4), can you please provide some more details?

Comment: ok, you are creating customer at time of order, so now simply go to admin panel -> Customer (Grid) ->check your currently created customer exisetd or not. 
  For 4th use this code to check weather your customer successfully created or not? 
          $customer = Mage::getModel("customer/customer"); 
        $customer->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getWebsite('admin')->getId()); 
         $customer->loadByEmail($email);

Comment: Thanks for the clearing. The answer is **no**, the customer is not created (it does not appear in the customer grid.